# public directory is not deployed on AWS Amplify

Tags: reactjs, apple-sign-in, aws-amplify

I am working on a project built by React/IONIC. Now I'm trying to add social sign in to the application, and to do so I need to put a file in the following directory:
/.well-known/apple-app-site-association

But the issue is, whenever I try to deploy the app on Amplify (it's connected to github repo), it doesn't deploy /public folder.

My Amplify.yml file is as follows:

`version: 1.2.9 env: variables: REACT_APP_API_ENDPOINT: https://******.execute-api.ca-central-1.amazonaws.com/staging frontend: phases: preBuild: commands: ['npm ci'] build: commands: ['npm run build'] artifacts: baseDirectory: build files: - '**/*' cache: paths: - 'node_modules/**/*'`

I would really appreciate your help here.

Comment: Did you get any solutions for this?

Comment: what do you see in build artifacts ?

Answer (score 2):

contents of public folder are deployed on root folder. So you /.well-known/apple-app-site-association will be available from https://<yourdomian.com>/.well-known/apple-app-site-association

You will have to add custom Rewrites and Redirect in AWS Amplify in AWS Console as the default Rewrite will redirect all request to Index.html for React App to handle

Answer (score 1):

So far I just deployed a React app on Amplify.
And I do not ask in `amplify.yml` the deployment of the `public/` folder. Rather I create a build of my project with a `yarn build`, which embeds the content of the public folder inside the new `build/` folder.
So I hope Ionic does not ask to deploy the public folder on top of `build/` folder.

I figured out as well that I needed to configure the URL routes inside rewrite and redirect menu of Amplify whenever my react app makes `GET` requests like `my-domain.com/privacy.pdf`.

As long as I did not specify the ".pdf" in the previously existing...

```
</^[^.]+$|\.(?!(css|gif|ico|jpg|js|png|txt|svg|woff|ttf|map|json)$)([^.]+$)/>   /index.html 200 (Rewrite)`
```

...rule, the routing was not able to fetch the privacy.pdf file.

I would suggest to look at the file extension of your logo too if the file extension of the sign you try to load is not included in the rewrite rule.

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR

Remove all of your redirects, so it will host the public folder and its contents.
[image]

There's no need to redeploy the server. The changes are made on the fly.